# How to provide testing credentials for the Goole Workspace Marketplace Review Team?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace-add-ons

We need your help.

We are a team developing a GoogleSheets Add-on. We submitted our add-on but the review team replied: "We have identified we need **additional testing credentials (test login)** in order to test the functionality of your App. Please share them with our team in order to proceed with the review process" (See the figure below).

[An E-mail from Google Workspace Marketplace Reviews Team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6i3v.jpg)

Could you please tell us how to provide the so-called "testing credentials" when re-submitting our add-on? For example, how to allow the review team account (gsmtestuser@marketplacetest.net) to test our add-on freely?

Thanks in advance.